# Android Studio 1.3 will not work with jcenter() Android Repository

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, jcenter

Project build.gradle

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Module build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mark.god_dam_supportlib"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v21:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

tried:
Putting the URL for bintray in the jcenter()
.
Disable offline mode
Made sure jcenter was in Project Structure - > Project - > [Android Plugin Repository && Default Library Repository].
Toggled disable offline mode.
Removed and reinstalled Android Support Repository, 
Android Support Library (many times).
No network proxy.
Set the .gradle to 777.

No Matter what get on a gradle sync:

Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v21:22.2.1
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog

Click on “ Install Repository and sync project”
Error message in the “Install Missing Components” dialog:

Loading SDK information...
Ignoring unknown package filter 'extra-android-m2repository'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.

As well in red at the bottom of “Install Missing Components” dialog”
Imstailed Failed: Please check your network conection and try again. You may continue creating your project, but it will not compile correctly without the missing components

On a Gradle build get:

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v21:22.2.1.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v21/22.2.1/appcompat-v21-22.2.1.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v21/22.2.1/appcompat-v21-22.2.1.jar
>            file:/home/usr/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v21/22.2.1/appcompat-v21-22.2.1.pom
>            file:/home/usr/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v21/22.2.1/appcompat-v21-22.2.1.jar
>            file:/home/usr/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v21/22.2.1/appcompat-v21-22.2.1.pom
>            file:/home/usr/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v21/22.2.1/appcompat-v21-22.2.1.jar
>        Required by:
>            Name_ofApp_folder:app:unspecified

Checked Google, Stack Over Flow.

Box is an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS straight up desktop.

Went as far as trying to down load the  Android Support Repository manually could find a download page.

As An Aside used these “ Android Support Repository” first quarter of the year with out any grief (need to update one!).

Completely and totally out of ideas and getting dangerously low on patience as well

Answer (score 2):

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v21:22.2.1 Install Repository and sync project

That is because there is no artifact named `com.android.support:appcompat-v21`. It is called `com.android.support:appcompat-v7`, and you already have a `compile` statement for it. Delete the `compile` statement for `com.android.support:appcompat-v21`.

Note that none of this has anything to do with JCenter, despite your question title.